# Percentual floating containers inside percentual container

Tags: layout, html, liquid

I have a simple problem which i cannot figure out. Look at this html code:

```
    <div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="active">pagina's</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">kamers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">over ons</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfloats"></div>
        <div id="cmscontent">
            <div id="sidebar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="overzicht active">overzicht van de pagina's</a></li>
                    <li class="last"><a href="#" class="toevoegen">pagina toevoegen</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="main">
                <h1 class="maintitle">
                    overzicht van de pagina's
                </h1>
                <div id="maincontent">
                    sdfsd
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfloats"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
width: 84%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#content {
margin-top: 50px;
min-width: 1140px;
}

#cmscontent {
background-color: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
padding: 44px 30px 44px 30px;
position: relative;
z-index: 3;
}

#sidebar{
padding: 14px 24px 14px 24px;
width: 306px;
background-color: #f8f8f8;
float: left;
}

#main {
float: left;
margin-left: 80px;
width: 100%;
}
```

The problem is that the last container: #main, standard is only as wide as the content it has. So i'm obliged to add a fixed width to it (px). The whole point of my design is that i have floating percentual divs so that's a bummer. Adding 100% width or any other number in %, also has problems of its own..

Is there anyone that a solution for me?

Thank you!

http://www.mathijsdelva.be/cms/

I haven't finetuned anything; i only just html'ed for Safari as of the moment.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that the last container: #main, standard is only as wide as the content it has.

Tried using display: block for #main ?

What are you actually trying to do here? Are you trying to make a flexible design?

Comment: Doesn't help. What i'm trying to do is indeed make a flexible liquid design: when you resize your browser window, all elements gently scale according to the browser window (just like one giant table). And everything's working great, except for that inner #main div, that just won't scale itself to its parent container..